# How to force ViewController to unload?

Tags: ios

I have an application that runs on background because it's needs to use Location Update. however, since i don't want to consume battery. I would like to make sure that all view controller is unloaded when app switch to run on background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forcing your view controller to unload is not going to save any battery life.  It's best to let the operating system worry about taking your app out of memory when it needs to.  If you're using the background mode that notifies your application when the user has travelled a significant amount you need to worry about this even less since your app is not actually running in the background but only given a chance to respond to location changes.  If you're using the constant location background mode (for GPS apps, etc.) this is a little bit more of an issue.

Comment: Thanks Paul ... i'm using constant location update because I need it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to unload the view controllers, but you do need to turn off location updates. If you are starting location updates in your App Delegate, put in something like this:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [myLocationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

You can also do this in the `viewWillDisappear:` method if your location manager is started in a different place than the App Delegate.